# js active button when number of input is 10 characters

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a disabled button changed into active button automatically using js when the number of input is 10 character in the input field.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="client_phone1" placeholder="01**********">
<button type="submit" formaction="{{url('/client-mobile-login')}}" disabled class="mobile-login__button">CONTINUE
                </button>
```

in this input field number of character is 10 then the submit button will active actomatically
what will be the js code?

Comment: add an `input` event listener on the input and check the length of the text in the input field every time this event is triggered. When the length of the input value is more than 10, remove the `disabled` attribute from the button.

Answer (score 0):

first add event listener to the input, then check if the value is equal to 10 and disable the button.

```
<input type="text" name="Thing" id="Thing" value="" />
<button type="submit" formaction="{{url('/client-mobile-login')}}" id='mybtn' class="mobile-login__button">CONTINUE
</button>

window.onload = function() {

  /* event listener */
  document.getElementById("Thing").addEventListener('keyup', doThing);

  /* function */
  function doThing() {
    console.log(this.value)
    if (this.value.length === 10) {
      document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("mybtn").disabled = false;
   
    }
  }

}
```

Edit: Example on JSFiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yb8ae9s/1/)

Comment: I edit the post and share JSFiddle, you need to add id to the input and change the id of button like i do @sharifahmed

Comment: I edit my post you need keyup for this. @sharifahmed